# How to rotate icon smoothly?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can't rotate the icon smoothly, I'm not sure why if anyone could help I will very much appreciate it!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

    <!-- style -->
    <style media="screen">
      div{
          background:red;
          width:20px;
          height:60px;
      }
      .rB {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        transition: all 2s linear;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <button id="button" type="button" name="button">Rotate</button>
    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
    <div></div>

    <!-- script -->
    <script>
      $(function(){
        $("#button").on('click', function(){
          $(this).siblings().toggleClass('rB');
          });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've added a div
https://codepen.io/SalahGfx/pen/yvJqVO

Comment: try adding this `body {  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); }` Or `body {  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }` on css

Comment: doesn't work bro

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Move the top script element inside the head element at least.

Comment: The issue appears to be specifically about FontAwesome’s `<svg>` icons. It begins to works, if the `fa-twitter` class is removed from the resulting `<svg>` element. Most likely, FontAwesome removes any transitioning CSS property state from its icons.

Comment: why it is invalid, they say put the script inside the body so the script runs after the complete load of the page, right?

Comment: Somebody edited your error so I rolled this back to what you wrote.

Comment: so what's the solution Rob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css animations to do that

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

    <!-- style -->
    <style media="screen">
  
      .rB {
        color: #03a9f4;
        animation-name: spin;
        animation-duration: 5000ms;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-timing-function: linear; 
      }
      @keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <button id="button" type="button" name="button">Rotate</button>
    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>

    <!-- script -->
    <script>
      $(function(){
        $("#button").on('click', function(){
          $(this).siblings().toggleClass('rB');
          });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You are losing the  tag as mentioned on their docs:
[image]

Notice how if you wrap the  tag in another div you will get the same behavior as your div. However, this is going to rotate around the center making your icon go around in a not so pretty way since the div is larger than the icon:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

    <!-- style -->
    <style media="screen">
      div{
          width:4px;
          height:4px;
      }
      .rB {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        transition: all 2s linear;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <button id="button" type="button" name="button">Rotate</button>
    <div class="tester"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i><div>
    <!-- script -->
    <script>
      $(function(){
        $("#button").on('click', function(){
          $(this).siblings().toggleClass('rB');
          });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks bro but that's not the problem, I mean I know other alternative

Comment: look https://codepen.io/SalahGfx/pen/yvJqVO why the div rotate smoothly and the icon doesn't what should I add or change

Comment: hmm let me take a look.

Comment: @SalahEddine issue is with your siblings not getting the font awesome icon. I can write up solution if you'd like

Comment: please write it

Comment: @SalahEddine updated with explanation. hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: clever way of doing it, thank you so much for your time <3 I will fix it with transform-origin and change width and height of the div

Comment: https://codepen.io/SalahGfx/pen/NyreBa give me your opinion about it and thank you so much again

Comment: @SalahEddine Nice work! It looks great.  Best of luck in your coding journey.